# Modifying VBA macro to add multiple empty rows at any place in a spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to be able to add empty rows at any place in an Excel spreadsheet. I need to specify a variety of different empty rows to enter at various rows in the spreadsheet. e.g Insert 100 empty rows starting from row 99.

I am new to macros and have copied a macro from the Internet and tried to adapt it, but I can't get the starting row correct. I've noted the parts of the code I'm confused about in the code comments.

```
Sub test()
Dim j As Long, r As Range

h = 0

j = 0


h = InputBox("type starting row")

j = InputBox("type the number of rows to be inserted")

Set r = Range("A2")  'Problem here -- I need to be able to change this to value from h'

Range(r.Offset(h, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert

Set r = Cells(r.Row + j, 1)

'MsgBox r.Address(the apostrophe in the beginning of this line makes this line non operable)


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Set r = Range("A2")` use `Set r = Range(h)` instead.  Other than that, I don't know what's not working with this.  You need to be more specific. What you've tried. What errors you are getting, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

'You should give your variables meaningfull names
'But I will leave them as h and j for now.
Dim h As Integer
Dim j As Integer

j = InputBox("How many rows do you want?")

h = InputBox("At what line do you want them?")

    'You can use the variable in the range, this is how
    Range("A" & h).Select

    'This is called a FOR loop, google them - they are easy to use and a basic part of programming.
    For i = 1 To j
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    Next i

End Sub
```

Note: This is not the most elegant solution, It is mainly written to be easy to understand.

You could also shorten it down a bit by not first selecting a range and then inserting at the selection like this:

```
For i = 1 To j
Range("A" & h).EntireRow.Insert
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a couple of tweaks to the code -- it's very close to working as is. See my comments in the amended code below.

```
Sub test()
Dim j As Long, r As Range

h = 0

j = 0


h = InputBox("type starting row")

j = InputBox("type the number of rows to be inserted")

'I moved this up one row so that the inserted rows are just below row h.
Set r = Range("A1")

'The second argument indicates the address of the bottom of the range. 
'This needs to take h into account so that the difference between the top and bottom is j rows.
Range(r.Offset(h, 0), r.Offset(h + j - 1, 0)).EntireRow.Insert

'The rest of the code wasn't doing anything, so I removed it.

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent it works thank you so much for your help, it has made my life much easier.

Comment: @BKelly Welcome to the site! Glad I could help. Please take a moment to read this help page: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I prefer this method of answering +1